# How to setup database tables that will store tabular data?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm going to have a website that will have millions of tables (literal HTML tables with data in them) so I will need to store that. I'm battling with issue of whether each table row should be stored as a separate record in the database or if I should just store the entire table as JSON encoded data (or similar format).

The reason I am questioning this is that I want to allow users to have access to change data in each of the HTML tables and I want them to be able to just change data in one table cell for example, without having to go through editing the entire table.

It just seems like if I store entire table as one value it could be messy to change just one cell as I'd probably have to just replace entire table value each time instead of doing search and replace. However, if I store each table row as a record, I will have billions of records which could get out of hand quickly as I want to keep old versions in storage as well (in another DB table).

If I store each row as separate record, it will also have to be super duper relational as HTML tables will have headings, sub headings, and so on.

I have done some calculations and these are rough numbers:

~912 total businesses
~800 average locations in US
~729,600 total tables
~72 million total table rows

Here's how table will work from UI perspective so you can understand how data will be handled and manipulated.

[image: table description]

Comment: What would they be searching on to even locate a table to begin with?

Comment: @DrewPierce I'm not sure I understand the question.  In a nutshell, I will have a table for each business location so each business location will have its own table (and backups of their old table versions). The business owner will be able to edit it how they want to, to include their relevant business information.  However, individual users will also be able to edit specific parts of the table as well.

Comment: @Basic I do have relational data.  I'll have business names, then individual business locations, then each business location will have one of the tables of its own.  I don't know much about NoSQL or how it works in regards to how it handles relational data, but I definitely do have it.

Comment: Er? Businesses contain locations which contain items which belong to a group. There's no part of the model which *isn't* relational.

Comment: Apologies, I completely mis-read the question. Too many tabs open...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't store HTML in the database -- just store the raw data, that's what databases are for. Then you can use PHP to format it on the fly however you like, be it an HTML table on a web page, a JSON-encoded string for an API query, high-level reporting, or a CSV file export. You'll need a table for businesses:

```
CREATE TABLE business (
    id UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    address ...
    city ...
);
```

One for locations of a business:

```
CRATE TABLE location (
    id UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    business_id UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL REFERENCES business(id),
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    description ...
    KEY (business_id)
);
```

And one for items of a location:

```
CREATE TABLE item (
    id UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    location_id UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL REFERENCES location(id),
    type VARCHAR(255),
    name VARCHAR(255),
    size VARCHAR(255),
    discount UNSIGNED INT,
    KEY (location_id)
);
```

You'll likely want to tweak indexes and key uniqueness based on your requirements. I imagine you'll want a unique key on (location.business_id + location.name) and (item.location_id + item.name).

Comment: Hi Alex, I would have never stored HTML in the database.  It was just a matter of whether I should store entire table data as JSON encoded or similar in one record, or store each individual table row as its own record. If I do the latter, I would also need hierarchy within row records because rows are in certain order in the table, and some rows might be headings or subheadings as well.

Comment: Store each individual table row as its own record. That's what databases are for. If you need ordering, just add a `sequence` column to the items table. Don't store headings, that's meta-data and doesn't belong in the table.

Comment: I will need to have headings within the table in order to group items together. By headings, I simply mean some table rows will have `colspan="3"` for example and stretch across table.  And then all items in that "group" will be underneath that heading. Here's an updated image of the table with said headings: http://postimg.org/image/7glo7eb7t/

Comment: These group values do not belong in the table as discrete rows. They're attributes of an individual row, and as such, should be stored with each row. I.e., add a `type` column to the `items` table, then `ORDER BY type` in your query. Then in your code loop that builds the HTML table, when you detect a change from one type to another, you output a new header row.

Comment: But in hundreds of thousands of these tables, there will be many types of groups.  So should I have a table just for these groups too?  What if type is like 10 words long, wouldn't it be better to have an `item_groups` table and then just have `id` and `name` columns in there?

Comment: Probably -- it depends on your data. If you only have handful of short groups, I'd just store the group name. If you have hundreds or thousands of groups with potentially long names, then yeah -- I'd create a related `group` table and store  the associated `group_id` in the `item` table. This has the added benefit of being able to easily lock down new group creation to certain users.

Comment: Note: You probably want to pick a name other than `group` since that's a reserved word in SQL.

Comment: Yea I definitely won't use the word `group`.  I have another question and that should be all. I'm going to have multiple group levels, up to 4.  So it can be like heading, subheading, 2nd level sub heading, and 3rd level sub heading. How should I handle these?  Should `item` be assigned to first sub heading, and then in `items_groups` table I would have `id`, `name`, `parent` maybe where the `parent` points back to the group's `id`?  Or is there a better/simpler way to do this?

Comment: Give me an example of your hierarchy. Do you mean something like: Drinks -> Beer -> Belgian -> Tripel?

Comment: Correct, that's a good example.  Most items will not have 4 levels of hierarchy, but it's in the design requirements to have up to 4 levels. So in your example, some beer brand items might fit under Beer, but some might fit all the way down into Tripel category.

Comment: There are many ways to represent hierarchies in a relational system, the `parent` method is common and just fine. Then you'd have to determine, can you use one set of groups for all businesses, or does each business need to have its own set (in which case, you need `business_id` column in the `groups` table.

Comment: More often than not, each business would have different groups.  Yes some categories might be shared for commonly named products, but a lot of businesses have their own naming conventions. So yes I could add `business_id` to the `groups` table, that won't be a problem.  Any other tips or advice you got?  I think I'm set as far as DB structure and design goes. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just note, with the data stored in its raw one-row-per-item form, you can now quite trivially handle things like, "Give me a list of all Belgian Tripels and what stores sell them." In the whole-set-of-items-as-one-JSON-doc model, that's very difficult and very slow. Good luck.

Comment: Yep exactly. I have much more control over the data this way, whereas if it was JSON format for entire table it would be a lot of parsing and searching and just a messy solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can look into NoSQL solutions like MongoDB and store your tables as items in collections. MongoDB should be efficient in handling tables stored in JSON format

For SQL options the answer depends on the size of your tables - if tables will be big then store entire table in JSON format will not be good in terms of retriving and updating table data. If tables are small then its a viable option.

Comment: Table rows will range anywhere from 30 up to maybe 300 or so.  The advantage of storing entire table data as JSON means tables can be different (i.e. have different amounts of columns) whereas if they're stored as rows, I'll have to set some boundaries they'll all have to abide by. Hmm.

Answer (score -1):

You can use PHP with either `mysql_connect`, `mysql_select_db`, `mysql_query` and the `mysql_fetch_row`.

On the CSS side you setup the following:

```
table.db-table      
table.db-table th   
table.db-table td
```

Then once these tables are drawn by your PHP code, you can design some more .CSS to perform inline editing within cell under column. You would need JavaScript or go with jQuery Framework.

You can also use PHP's PDO instead of `mysql` as written above.

```
$dbh = new PDO("sybase:host=$host;dbname=$dbname, $user, $pass");
$q = $dbh->prepare("DESCRIBE tablename");
$q->execute();
$table_fields = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

You'll need jQuery to edit individual table cells, or to make it possible for your users to be able to do that on-the-fly. You may want to check the [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) plugin.

EDIT: To answer the question regarding the setup of a database and all of its tables, I'll try: Well, you could use real MySQL tables. If you know the column names when you get the data you could simply make up a suitable table name (BTW, make sure you make these up yourself), create the table with the necessary names.

And you can always ask the database for the table’s schema, if you ever needed to, using `show_column` query.